# Getting a NullPointerException when trying to change a button's background resource using a FOR loop

Tags: android, kotlin

Basically the app is able to run and everything up till i inserted any of the codes

- `clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(ant)`
- `clickableViews[i].text = "cardback"`
- `clickableViews[i].textSize = 0.0F`

into the for loop

`for (i in 0..15){}`

*I am a complete beginner at this so please let me know where i made a mistake in my code and any other info you need. Much appreciated!*

**.kt file:**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.betaberry.databinding.FragmentGameBinding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_game.*
import  com.example.betaberry.R.drawable.*

class GameFragment : Fragment() {
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentGameBinding>(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_game,container,false)


        val pictures: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(
            ant, gab, meg, dam, dyl, wp, me, kek, ant, gab, meg, dam, dyl, wp, me, kek)

//These squares are buttons in an array
        val clickableViews = arrayOf(
            square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6, square7, square8,
            square9, square10, square11, square12, square13, square14, square15, square16) 


        val cardBack = cardback
        var clickCount = 0
        var turnOver = false
        var lastClicked = -1


        pictures.shuffle()

        for (i in 0..15){

            clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(ant)
//if everything below this is removed (except "return binding.root"), the NullPointerException points to this line
            clickableViews[i].text = "cardback"
            clickableViews[i].textSize = 0.0F

clickableViews[i].setOnClickListener {
                if (clickableViews[i].text == "cardback" && !turnOver) {
                    clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(pictures[i])
                    clickableViews[i].setText(pictures[i])
                    if (clickCount == 0) {
                        lastClicked = i
                    }
                    clickCount++
                }

                else if (clickableViews[i].text !in "cardback") {
                    clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(cardBack)
                    clickableViews[i].text = "cardback"
                    clickCount--
                }

                if (clickCount == 2) {
                    turnOver = true
                    if (clickableViews[i].text == clickableViews[lastClicked].text) {
                        clickableViews[i].isClickable = false
                        clickableViews[lastClicked].isClickable = false
                        turnOver = false
                        clickCount = 0
                    }
                }

                else if (clickCount == 0) {
                    turnOver = false
                }
            } //setOnClickListener end

        } //for loop end

        return binding.root

    } //onCreateView end


} //GameFragment end
```

**Error from Logcat:**

```
2020-03-07 21:19:10.613 5547-5547/com.example.betaberry E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.betaberry, PID: 5547
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.betaberry.GameFragment.onCreateView(GameFragment.kt:67)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

**Most of the code i've used is followed from this video tutorial:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGvjScKcW1s

Comment: The stack trace will tell you where the problem is. You can edit your question and copy-paste it in if you need help interpretting it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 there is no problem building, installing, and running the app on my phone. It's just that when i remove all the code below the For loop and only include either the .text/.setBackgroundResource/.textSize line of code into the For loop, when i enter that fragment (after pressing a button), the app crashes. The Logcat on android studio also doesnt seem to flag any errors.

Comment: There must be something in logcat, cross check again by selecting your app.

Comment: Make sure you haven't filtered out your app from LogCat. There will *always* be a stack trace if it crashes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 
@HaiderSaleem

I managed to find the error messages and i've added it into the post above, but i dont really understand the problem. 
Is the main problem the `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference`?
What does it really mean?

Comment: If you remove these 3 lines and leave only setOnClickListener() does it work properly?

Comment: @forpas Nope it doesnt. Though i havent exactly tested at which line the program fails and crashes, as well as the Logcat error messages when it fails. If you are interested, I can do the testing and get back to you?

Comment: @forpas it still seems to leave a null pointer exception. The thing i cant understand now is how come my buttons are giving off a null value. Any help from anyone?

Comment: Also, most of the code used here was from a video tutorial i've followed (link indicated above) and tried implementing into my fragment, but the Null Pointed Exception appears and i cant really figure out why. Anyone can give me any insight?

Comment: @bartonstanley I'm sorry, im extremely new to this so I still do not understand quite a few concepts and how they work (i.e. 'onStart method', 'inflating the binding', 'in another method'). if you have links to resources that I can read up on on these topics, I would be grateful if you could share them. 
Also, what would be the reason to move all those code to the onStart method and how does it prevent the NPE? Thanks.

Comment: The video using an `Activity` not a `Fragment`.  For instance, at 27:07 the beginning of the class is definition is: `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {` not `class GameFragment : Fragment()` as shown above.   At the end of the video he is still editing the same file.  Is there a later video where he modifies the app to use a `Fragment`?

Comment: @bartonstanley no there isnt. His program does not make use of any Fragments. What I did was to try and adapt his code into my own program that has a Fragment and I dont know if that may have caused the error I am having now and how it causes the error.

Comment: Ok, I see.  I've posted a tentative answer below.

Comment: BTW, if you are satisfied with my answer will you kindly set it as the accepted answer and upvote it?  To set it as the accepted answer click the grey checkmark to the left of your question.  To upvote the answer click the up arrow (triangle) to the left of your question.  This is the customary way to say "thank you" on stack overflow.  It will increase the answerer's reputation.  I have upvoted your question because so your reputation is increased so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @bartonstanley Yup I had already done both after your solution worked. Just that since my reputation is <15, the upvote isn't quite considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `View` is not set up until after `onCreateView` executes, which means that the buttons are not yet available via the synthetic import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_game.*`.  There are two possible solutions.

### Access the `Button`s through the `binding` variable

For example, use `binding.square1` to access that `Button`.

### Access the `Button`s through the synthetic import in `onStart`

To access the `Button`s through the synthetic import override `onStart` and put the logic in there.  Note that `onCreateView` of a `Fragment` is different that `onCreate` of an `Activity`.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.betaberry.databinding.FragmentGameBinding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_game.*
import com.example.betaberry.R.drawable.*

class GameFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentGameBinding>(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_game,container,false)

        return binding.root
    } //onCreateView end

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val pictures: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(
            ant, gab, meg, dam, dyl, wp, me, kek, ant, gab, meg, dam, dyl, wp, me, kek)

        //These squares are buttons in an array
        val clickableViews = arrayOf(
            square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6, square7, square8,
            square9, square10, square11, square12, square13, square14, square15, square16) 

        val cardBack = cardback
        var clickCount = 0
        var turnOver = false
        var lastClicked = -1

        pictures.shuffle()

        for (i in 0..15){
            clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(ant)
            clickableViews[i].text = "cardback"
            clickableViews[i].textSize = 0.0F

            clickableViews[i].setOnClickListener {
                if (clickableViews[i].text == "cardback" && !turnOver) {
                    clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(pictures[i])
                    clickableViews[i].setText(pictures[i])
                    if (clickCount == 0) {
                        lastClicked = i
                    }
                    clickCount++
                }

                else if (clickableViews[i].text !in "cardback") {
                    clickableViews[i].setBackgroundResource(cardBack)
                    clickableViews[i].text = "cardback"
                    clickCount--
                }

                if (clickCount == 2) {
                    turnOver = true
                    if (clickableViews[i].text == clickableViews[lastClicked].text) {
                        clickableViews[i].isClickable = false
                        clickableViews[lastClicked].isClickable = false
                        turnOver = false
                        clickCount = 0
                    }
                }

                else if (clickCount == 0) {
                    turnOver = false
                }
            } //setOnClickListener end

        } //for loop end
    }
} //GameFragment end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. I had a suspicion that the problem had something to do with the buttons not being available/generated yet thus returning a 'null' value (from all the various other NullPointerException cases I've read through) since there didn't seem to be a problem with the array code nor buttons, but I dont know enough to know what to do.

Comment: Anyway, I do have some questions about your solution that i hope can help further my understanding. 
**1)** Are the items in the .xml file (do you call it view?) only accessible after the `return binding.root` code is run? What does `return binding.root` even mean or do?
**2)** How come the program in (https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-starter-apps/tree/master/AndroidTrivia-Starter) is able to access their buttons without problems?
**3)** What does the `override fun onStart() { super.onStart() }` code do and how it solves the problem I faced?

Comment: 1) Yes. `onCreateView` *inflates* the xml file to create a `View` and returns it (note its return type). It literally creates the `Button`s. However, until it is returned to the Android system those items are not available via the synthetic import. 2) That program can access the `Button`s because it uses the `binding` variable, rather than the synthetic import. It uses `binding.submitButton`, not just `submitButton`.  3) `onStart` [is always executed after `onCreateView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating) so the view is guaranteed to exist when it executes.

Comment: By "synthetic import" I mean the line `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_game.*`  This is a Kotlin thing that makes it easier to access the `Button`s, etc., once they have been inflated and returned to Android.  In Java you would have to have a line of code to fetch each `Button`, which in this case would be a lot of extra code.  Now, as to which way is better, using `binding` or doing it in `onStart` I'm not sure.  Personally, I'd do in it `onStart` but Google's example does not so I guess it is ok to do it that way!

Comment: I see I see! And the `onStart` code is part of the many codes that controls the lifecycles of the fragments right? Also, could you explain about `override` like what it is, what it does, and how it's used? or if you have a link to a page that explains this concept so I can read up on it. Your explanations thus far has been very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Overriding is part of the larger object-oriented concept of *inheritance*. There's lots of info on that but here is info for game developers: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-the-oop-principle-of-inheritance--gamedev-2536  It is in Java, not Kotlin so once you get the concept, here's the Kotlin link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance.

Comment: Once you have a handle on that look at the android [`fragment` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/fragment) since that is what your `gamefragment` class inherits from. you'll see that it defines the methods you are overriding.

Comment: This is a little more info than you'd normally get on stackoverflow.  Not everyone will be so accommodating, and some people can be downright harsh.  If someone is harsh to you, don't get discouraged! Asking questions like these are exactly what you need to do to be successful at this. Be aware that it will not always be easy but if you find this is your passion, don't give up! I hope that these links will help you get to the point where you can find many such answers on your own.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thank you very much! Will keep in mind what you have said. You've been very helpful and I am very appreciative!